# Taking a SOQL statment outside of loop

Tags: apex, trigger, soql, loop

I need help taking the SOQL out of the for loop. I know I probably need to map the data. But how I would do this and achieve the same result I am not quite sure about. I know the answer is probably fairly simple as this is not a complicated block of code but I am unfamiliar with APEX and this type of syntax so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
trigger Add_Event_ID on Hum_data__c (before insert) {

    for (Hum_data__c h : Trigger.new) {
    
        String callEventID;
        callEventID = 
            [SELECT call__Event_ID__c 
            FROM call__Call_Detail__c 
            WHERE call__Call_Detail__c.call__Callid__c = :h.call__callid__c 
            LIMIT 1].call__Event_ID__c;
        
        h.call__Event_ID__c = callEventID;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this code, here I'm assuming call__Callid__c is lookup field

```
trigger Add_Event_ID on Hum_data__c (before insert) {
    
    List<Id> callIdList = new List<Id>();
    for (Hum_data__c h : Trigger.new) {
        callIdList.add(h.call__callid__c);
    }
    
    Map<Id,Id> IdMap = new Map<Id,Id>();
    for(call__Call_Detail__c cc : [SELECT call__Event_ID__c,call__Callid__c 
            FROM call__Call_Detail__c 
            WHERE call__Callid__c IN :callIdList] ){
                IdMap.put(cc.call__Callid__c,cc.call__Event_ID__c);
        
    }
    
    for (Hum_data__c h : Trigger.new) {
        h.call__Event_ID__c = IdMap.get(h.call__callid__c);
    }
       
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a commented example of how this code could be restructured using a map to associate the id values to one another.

As an aside, don't use `String` for `Id` values. It is safer to use the correct data type whenever you can.

```
trigger Add_Event_ID on Hum_data__c(before insert) {
    // a place to store our results
    Map<Id, Id> callIdToEventIdMap = new Map<Id, Id>();

    // gather all of the call ids
    for (Hum_data__c h : Trigger.new) {
        callIdToCallDetailMap.put(h.call__callid__c, null);
    }

    // make the query
    for (call__Call_Detail__c detailRecord : [
        SELECT call__Event_ID__c
        FROM call__Call_Detail__c
        WHERE call__Callid__c IN :callIdToEventIdMap.keyset()
    ]) {
        // match the call id with the event id. this will also push out any duplicates
        callIdToEventIdMap.put(detailRecord.call__Callid__c, detailRecord.call__Event_ID__c);
    }

    // put the event id value from the map into the field on the trigger record
    for (Hum_data__c h : Trigger.new) {
        h.call__Event_ID__c = callIdToEventIdMap.get(h.call__callid__c);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer is similar to other two answers, but with some additional performance and safety check which I think should be a good practice, ie:

1. Only run query when necessary
2. Only do assignment when reference data exists

Generally the pattern is:

1. Build a map collection to filter the query and store the corresponding query result
2. Iterate the trigger list and do the assignment based on the map's key (from step #1)

```java
trigger Add_Event_ID on Hum_data__c (before insert) {

    // Step 1

    // build the collection
    Map<Id, Id> eventIdBycallId = new Map<Id, Id>();
    for (Hum_data__c h : Trigger.new) {
        eventIdBycallId.put(h.call__callid__c, null);
    }
    // important! Only run SOQL query when the Map is not empty
    if (!eventIdBycallId.isEmpty()) {
        for (call__Call_Detail__c ccd : [
                SELECT call__Callid__c, call__Event_ID__c 
                FROM call__Call_Detail__c 
                WHERE call__Callid__c = :eventIdBycallId.keySet()
            ]) {
            eventIdBycallId.put(ccd.call__callid__c, ccd.call__Event_ID__c);
        }
    }
    
    // Step 2 

    for (Hum_data__c h : Trigger.new) {
        // important to check if your map has the corresponding key 
        // to prevent NullPointerException
        if (eventIdBycallId.containsKey(h.call__callid__c)) {
            h.call__Event_ID__c = eventIdBycallId.get(h.call__callid__c);
        }
        // ...
        // other lines of code
    }
}
```